# Agregar clave valor en HEADER HTTP VOLLEY ANDROID

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 public void servicio_GET_MOVS(final Context context, String request, final Response.Listener<GetMovements> listener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    HashMap<String, String> headerParams = new HashMap<>();
    headerParams.put("key", "45646B");
    headerParams.put("base_number","14");
    int method = Request.Method.POST;
    String serviceURL = URLLocal;
    String req = "";
    try {
        req = request;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, null);
        objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method,serviceURL, GetMovements.class, req, listener, errorListener);
        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown", e);
    }
}
```

como puedo agregar mis headersParams a la peticcion http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre escribe el metodo `getHeaders` del objeto `Request<T>`( en tu caso `ObjectRequest`) y  alli le especificas tus headers:

```
//...

req = request;
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, null);

objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method,serviceURL, GetMovements.class, req, listener, errorListener){
     @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            params.put("MiNuevoHeader", "Valor de tu header");  
            //...

            return params;  
    }
};
objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
//...
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Einer , y cuando diga muchisimas gracias es porque realmente este foro o como yo le llamo , mi pagina amiga , es tan asi de bueno solo por las personas que la conforman y tu eres un gran integrante, espero hallas tenido un buen anio y feliz año nuevo

Comment: Es un placer ayudar. Pero te funciono, verdad?

Comment: no te pude dar respuesta aceptada porque me daba que faltaban x cantidad de tiempo , el codigo no me dio errores ni nada y el servicio esta andando por lo que yo entiendo si anduvo